# При округлении до 2-х знаков после запятой, иногда округляется до 6 знаков с девятками

Tags: c#, математика, округление

Простейшее выражение

```
float a = 9 * 1.15f;
Math.Round(a, 2);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Должно выводиться 10,35, но выводится 10,349999.
В чём проблема и как это исправить?

Comment: попробуй использовать Decimal. Или же сначала флоат конвертирй в десимал, а потому уже округляй. Должно исправить проблему. На сколько я помню у флоатов какие-то сложности с дробными числами и они могут скакать

Comment: Не забывайте про разницу между хранением и представлением числа. Если хотите, чтобы выводилось 2 знака после запятой, используйте соответствующее форматирование при выводе. Внутреннее представление вещественных чисел не всегда 100% точное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Результат округления нужно чему-то присвоить :

```
a = Math.Round(a, 2);
```